# Installing grafana as current logged in user

Tags: unix, grafana

I am confused after seeing Grafana [installation steps](https://www.tecmint.com/install-grafana-analytics-in-centos-ubuntu-debian/) (pasted below) and want to understand how can I install and run Grapaha as me.

```
$ echo "deb https://packagecloud.io/grafana/stable/debian/ stretch main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
$ curl https://packagecloud.io/gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install grafana
```

Can someone explain what the above lines are doing, and how can I get grafana installed for my user.

When I ran

```
echo "deb https://packagecloud.io/grafana/stable/debian/ stretch main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
[sudo] password for agrawalo:
Sorry, user agrawalo is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list' as root.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it finally.

```
wget https://dl.grafana.com/oss/release/grafana-6.2.5.linux-amd64.tar.gz 
tar -zxvf grafana-6.2.5.linux-amd64.tar.gz
```

And then started Grafana by executing

```
./bin/grafana-server web
```

To run Grafana open your browser and go to http://localhost:3000/

There you will see the login page. Default username is admin and default password is admin.